# kubeflow UI shows "the site can't be reached" after deploy with CLI

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubeflow

I try to deploy kubeflow with the tutorial https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/gke/deploy/deploy-cli/ , after I run "kfctl apply -V -f ${CONFIG_FILE}" and finally I see "Applied the configuration Successfully!", then I wait an hour and try to visit "https://.endpoints..cloud.goog/" as tutorial described.

However, when I visit my url,  it shows "the site can't be reached".

And I try to "curl -k https://chukubeflow.endpoints.tchu-test.cloud.goog -v" , it shows:

```
* Rebuilt URL to: https://chukubeflow.endpoints.tchu-test.cloud.goog/
* Could not resolve host: chukubeflow.endpoints.tchu-test.cloud.goog
* Closing connection 0
```

It seems DNS resolve failed. Any suggestion for this problem?

Comment: add it to `/etc/hosts`, along with the ip address you get from `kubectl get ingress` and try again.

Comment: thx @suren,  when you say "add it",  could you tell a little detail about what "it" is here?  should I add "https://chukubeflow.endpoints.tchu-test.cloud.goog/" inside /etc/hosts?

Comment: yes. do `vim /etc/hosts`, and paste it in a new line `...cloud.goog         IP`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems no problem when I use a new oAuth and a new App ("tchu2kubeflow" instead of "tchukubeflow").  So I guess some fails happened before and remembered in the workflow